# cannot create a txt file

Tags: java, file-io

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Exercise4
{
String name = null;
public String nameInitials(String sentence)
{
PrintWriter outputStream = null;
try
{
    outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("abc.txt."));
    outputStream.println(sentence);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("File not found.");
    System.exit(0);
}
outputStream.close();
Scanner inputStream = null;
try
{
    inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("abc.txt."));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("File not found.");
    System.exit(0);
}
do
{
    String word = inputStream.next();
    char initial = word.charAt(0);
    name = initial+"."+name;
} while (inputStream.hasNext());
return name;
}
public void main(String[]args)
{
String initials = nameInitials("Bertrand Arthur William Russell");
System.out.println(initials);
}
}
```

Write a method called nameInitials that takes one String as argument, pertaining to somebody's full name and returns a String of the name's initials. Usage example,

```
String initials = nameInitials("Bertrand Arthur William Russell");
System.out.println(initials); //should print B.A.W.R.
```

I try to store the full name to a txt file and read the file. But I don't know why I cannot create the abc.txt file in the folder.

Comment: Why have you given file name as abc.txt.??? try using abc.txt

Comment: Always add the error you get.

Comment: don't forget If you want you may accept my answer. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This can fix your error, I tested it

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Exercise4
{
    static String name = null;

public static String nameInitials(String sentence) {
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\abc.txt"));
        outputStream.println(sentence);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\abc.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    do {
        String word = inputStream.next();
        char initial = word.charAt(0);
        name = initial + "." + name;
    } while (inputStream.hasNext());
    return name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String initials = nameInitials("Bertrand Arthur William Russell");
    System.out.println(initials);
}
 }
```

the path of file not should end of .txt. just .txt

Comment: I compile it and I found that the output is R.W.A.B.null.
How to remove the word null?

Comment: change: static String name = null; with static String name = "";

Comment: don't forget If you want you may accept my answer. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect it is creating the file "`abc.txt.`" at the project level If you want to create a file named `abc.txt` then you must change;

`new FileOutputStream("abc.txt.")` to `new FileOutputStream("abc.txt")`

and

`new FileInputStream("abc.txt.")` to `new FileInputStream("abc.txt")`

And if you want to create the file in a particular directory then provide the full path of that directory with the file name you want to create.

for ubuntu system;

```
new FileOutputStream("/home/java/abc.txt")
```

&

```
new FileInputStream("/home/java/abc.txt")
```

and for windows system;

```
new FileOutputStream("C:/java/abc.txt")
```

&

```
new FileInputStream("C:/java/abc.txt")
```